# Change the background of selected posts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use wordpress.

To beautify my site, I want to be able to change the background and color of that part by selecting a part of the writing.

[image]

I saw this in some sites but I don't know how to do it.

```css
p {
        margin: 60px;
        line-height: 36px;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
```

```html
 <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, est, tempore accusantium deserunt omnis non magnam,
        possimus ipsum incidunt corrupti quia? Libero rerum aspernatur consequuntur dolorem quisquam numquam debitis,
        inventore eaque minima corporis explicabo aliquid sit accusamus. Iste beatae aliquam itaque perferendis tempora
        ea sed mollitia quasi totam architecto nisi quia dolorum in laudantium quae eaque quidem consectetur dolor
        eligendi aperiam est, eveniet et similique. Veniam aperiam saepe maiores laboriosam quod necessitatibus aut ea
        ad facere repudiandae, sapiente sequi. Adipisci quia voluptas amet, error, dicta dolore aliquid accusantium
        similique harum ex, at quis consequatur fugit? Maiores modi dolore, magni est laboriosam suscipit obcaecati sint
        esse! Consequuntur, tempora sapiente! Possimus veniam laboriosam distinctio ipsam neque reiciendis minima
        nostrum et atque libero? Adipisci accusamus magni expedita saepe quis, vero quia accusantium. Quod iste dicta
        tempora delectus voluptatum! Distinctio, quaerat fugiat delectus quas commodi facere cupiditate quisquam nobis
        laudantium officia aperiam expedita praesentium laborum voluptatem non, harum ex vel odio molestias quae tempora
        tenetur. Sed soluta illo vero, impedit natus quo rerum dicta beatae iure amet consequuntur nihil laudantium!
        Harum laborum pariatur repudiandae dolore nobis adipisci iure natus veniam commodi voluptatum. Quos reiciendis
        impedit unde eligendi consequuntur, deleniti debitis repudiandae nostrum natus. Quas.
    </p>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the default "blue" color of selected text?

Comment: Hello.Yes. I mean exactly that.

Comment: Is there a way? Because I have seen this in some sites. That's why this case was very interesting to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
  ::selection {
            color: red;
            background: violet;
        }
```

```html
<p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, est, tempore accusantium deserunt omnis non magnam,
        possimus ipsum incidunt corrupti quia? Libero rerum aspernatur consequuntur dolorem quisquam numquam debitis,
        inventore eaque minima corporis explicabo aliquid sit accusamus. Iste beatae aliquam itaque perferendis tempora
        ea sed mollitia quasi totam architecto nisi quia dolorum in laudantium quae eaque quidem consectetur dolor
        eligendi aperiam est, eveniet et similique. Veniam aperiam saepe maiores laboriosam quod necessitatibus aut ea
        ad facere repudiandae, sapiente sequi. Adipisci quia voluptas amet, error, dicta dolore aliquid accusantium
        similique harum ex, at quis consequatur fugit? Maiores modi dolore, magni est laboriosam suscipit obcaecati sint
        esse! Consequuntur, tempora sapiente! Possimus veniam laboriosam distinctio ipsam neque reiciendis minima
        nostrum et atque libero? Adipisci accusamus magni expedita saepe quis, vero quia accusantium. Quod iste dicta
      <span>  tempora delectus voluptatum! Distinctio, quaerat fugiat delectus quas commodi facere cupiditate quisquam nobis
        laudantium officia aperiam expedita praesentium laborum voluptatem non, harum ex vel odio molestias quae tempora
        tenetur. Sed soluta illo vero, impedit natus quo rerum dicta beatae iure amet consequuntur nihil laudantium!</span>
        Harum laborum pariatur repudiandae dolore nobis adipisci iure natus veniam commodi voluptatum. Quos reiciendis
        impedit unde eligendi consequuntur, deleniti debitis repudiandae nostrum natus. Quas.
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your css

```css
 ::selection {
    color: <your-text-color>;
    background-color: <your-background-color>;
  }
```